# Unity игра не запускается в Браузере Exception: WebGLPlayer does not support synchronous Addressable loading

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, webgl

Ошибка возникает после загрузки игры в браузере(После Logo Unity)
[image: Ошибка при попытке запустить игру в Браузере]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема серьёзная. Ошибка вылазить когда пытаешься запустить игру через браузер(см.скриншот). Есть инфа что это проблема в локализации игры. Я ничего не понимаю помогите

Сама игра доступна по ссылке - https://yandex.ru/games/app/216582?draft=true&lang=ru

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Player settings]

Попробуйте использовать эти настройки в Building Settings и Player Settings. Для этого нужно зайти в file > build settings. В открывшемся окне выставить настройки как на первом скриншоте. Далее в этом же окне нажать на player settings. В открывшемся окне развернуть вкладку Publishing Settings и в этой вкладке выставить настройки как на втором скриншоте

Comment: опишите, пожалуйста, словами, что именно предлагаете.

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, текст ответа, нажав [edit]